# Is Swift removeSubrange fast enough?

Tags: arrays, swift, performance

When dealing with very large arrays, say, 75000 samples, is the `removeSubrange` function fast enough? Or should I be using any other faster method.

I can use `removeSubrange` in two ways as shown below. Is there a difference in computation time, specially for large sample sizes.

```
 import UIKit

 var xt1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

 var xt2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

 xt1.removeSubrange(ClosedRange(uncheckedBounds: (lower: 7, upper: 9)))

 xt2.removeSubrange(7...9)

 print("Method 1:", xt1)

 print("Method 2:", xt2)
```

Comment: Did *you* measure a difference? Did you *profile* your app with Instruments to see if those calls are a bottleneck in your app?

Comment: I haven't don't it yet Martin. Just curious about the difference in syntax.

Comment: But you asked about performance/computation time, not about syntax (and the answer is always: measure and profile first).

Comment: Ok, I will do it. Was wondering is somebody already knew !

Comment: Note that you call the *same* method in both cases, the only difference is how you create the range. Therefore I would bet that there is no performance difference at all.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much Martin :). But I will try to run the profiler too as you suggest.

Comment: @MartinR could you pls share you're opinion about my answer. Is it enough or what I could do better.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation `removeSubrange`.

> Complexity: O(n), where n is the length of the collection.

So small measurements for you.

```
var x = Array(repeating: "yes", count: 750000)
```

Than I use code of the Brad Larson for measurements:

```
func timeElapsedInSecondsWhenRunningCode(operation: ()->()) -> Double {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    return Double(timeElapsed)
}
```

So lets try to do measurements.

```
timeElapsedInSecondsWhenRunningCode {
    x.removeSubrange(4543...72000)
}
```

It will take 0.03 sec

Now you can do some measurement and find out.

This if full code that will do 32 iteration to measure performance with random ranges.

```
var x = Array(repeating: "yes", count: 750000)

func timeElapsedInSecondsWhenRunningCode(from: Int, to: Int, operation: ()->()) -> Double {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    return Double(timeElapsed)
}

struct Test {
    var range:(Int, Int)
    var time:Double
}

var mesurments = [Int:Test]()

for i in 0...32 {

    let from  = randomInt(min: 0, max: x.count/2)

    let to = randomInt(min: from, max: x.count)

    let z = x

    let time = timeElapsedInSecondsWhenRunningCode(from: from, to: to, operation: {
            x.removeSubrange(from...to)
    })

    x = z

    mesurments[i] = Test(range: (from, to), time: time)
}


func randomInt(min: Int, max:Int) -> Int {
    return min + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max - min + 1)))
}
```